# How it possible to rotate each Image with same button

Tags: android, image, rotation

[I https://i.stack.imgur.com/I26fq.png][1

> I have two Image. How it possible to rotate each Image with same button

Comment: add description here

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iswy7.png

Answer (score 1):

`imageView`, `angle`, `pivotX` & `pivotY` should be defined as per requirement

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```